# Размер диалога при ландшафтной ориентации

Tags: android

Есть activity  только для ландшафтной ориентации экрана, на ней вызывается диалог, возможно ли задать ширину диалога больше  высоты (ширины портретной ориентации) ?

Comment: А так получается:

    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    dialog.show();

Либо так:

    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

чтобы полностью закрыть Activity.

Answer (score 1):

создай нужный тебе layout в папке layouts-land